# Exit Div Only On Click Of Background With Javascript(Jquery) [For Popup]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am in a bit of a predicament. I have a popup currently, and I would like the popup to close when either the background is clicked, or the "ex out" button is clicked. Problem is, it will close the popup when the main box is clicked. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="newcommentcontainer">
    <div id="newcommentholder" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
        <form method="post" class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="exoutnewcommentholder" class="col-xs-12">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="exoutnewcomment"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="newcommenttitle" class="col-xs-12"> Add New Comment </div>
            <textarea id="commentinput" name="commentinput" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" placeholder="Type your Comment here."></textarea>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                <button id="createcommentbutton" class="col-xs-12" input type="submit" value="addcomment">Add Comment</button>
            </div>
            <div id="commentcharactercount" class="col-xs-12"> 0 / 500 Characters. </div>
            <input type="text" id="commentlengthholder" name="commentlengthholder" style="display:none">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

So basically, when `#newcommentcontainer` (First Div), is clicked on, the whole thing closes. If `#newcommentholder` is clicked, nothing happens, because that is what holds the information. Yet, if `#exoutnewcommentholder` is click, the whole thing closes as well.

Simply, I would like the whole thing to `display: none` when it is clicked EXCEPT if it is clicked within the `#newcommentholder` (excluding `ex out` button).

I have started with this JQuery:

```
    $("#newcommentcontainer").click(function(e) {
        $("#newcommentcontainer").css("display","none");
    });
```

But I am not sure on how to continue from here. Please help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 2 click handlers, the second one will prevent the propagation of click event from `newcommentholder` so that clicks inside that will not close the popup

```
$("#newcommentcontainer, #exoutnewcommentholder").click(function (e) {
    $("#newcommentcontainer").hide();
});
$('#newcommentholder').click(function (e) {
    //stop propagation to newcommentcontainer element
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

---

Another option you can try is(not tested) to check the target element is within `newcommentholder` like

```
$("#newcommentcontainer").click(function (e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.closest('#exoutnewcommentholder').length || !$target.closest('#newcommentholder').length) {
        $("#newcommentcontainer").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! I knew it had something to do with `stopPropagation()` but I had no idea how it would tie in. Thank you again! :)